# Accessing Local Web server on my LAN error

Tags: iis, web-server, local-area-network, localhost

I have looked at the other questions related to this on SO, Googled and looked in my Window Logs.

I have a local web site on a PC that is DHCP assigned.

It is a MVC web site using IIS Manager.

On the same PC as my web site I can view at as 'localhost' and by the DHCP address.

If I go to another PC on my LAN and type in the ip address of my local web site it tells me that the 'Page Can't be displayed'.

If I open a DOS prompt on that other PC I can PING the PC that hosts my website.

I know about LocalHosts but I would have to change the localhosts on each PC which is not a choice for me.  Besides, I thought as long as it was address by the IP address it would not be an issue.

Am I missing a config setting on my IIS somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your computer have a firewall ? If yes, try to open your HTTP port on the computer serving your website.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="HTTP TCP Port 80" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="HTTP TCP Port 139" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80
```

Does your IIS server is listening on your network IP ? Check this with your site bindings.
http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/mark-newnam/how-to-set-up-site-bindings-in-internet-information-services-iis/

Comment: Hi, thanks for such an early reply. When I turned off my firewall it works. So, looking at the setting I needed to allow HTTP web server through. Feel a bit stupid now. Thanks for the link!